# How to make the data tip of matlab figure show the image gray level color and not its RGB value?

Tags: matlab

I have images with gray level value and I'm displaying them using matlab imagesc function. However, when using the data tip with these figures the RGB value is displayed instead of the true gray level color. How can I change that to display the gray level color of each pixel of the image?

Comment: Is your image RGB or grey-scale? What is the value of `size(YourImage,3)`?

Comment: I used rgb2gray before calling imagesc

Answer (score 0):

Using `colormap(gray)` after your `imagesc()` function will convert the display image to grey scale.

`imagesc(image), colormap(gray)`

or

`imshow(uint8(image))` where `uint8()` is trying to scale the value to 0~255 if you need, or it will show the true grey value.